Time evolution of operators in the path integral formalism
I have studied the Hamiltonian formulation of non-relativistic quantum mechanics (NRQM) in detail but have limited knowledge of the path integral formulation.
In the interaction picture of the ordinary Hamiltonian formulation of NRQM, the evolution of an operator is written as
$$\mathcal{O}_I(t) = e^{iH_{0,S}t/\hbar} ~ \mathcal{O}_S ~ e^{-iH_{0,S}t/\hbar}$$
where $\mathcal{O}_S$ and $H_{0,S}$ are the operator and the time-independent part of the Hamiltonian, respectively, in the Schrödinger picture.
My question is: Is it possible to express the time evolution of an operator in the path integral formalism?
I understand that most of the path integral theory focuses on state vectors, but I am curious if the time evolution of operators can also be studied within this framework.

It is a different thing. In the path integration framework one usually directly obtains the time evolution operator, and with that, you can time evolve anything you want.

Hi SCh, Well, the operator and path integral formalism are formally equivalent, so any question in one should in principle be answerable in the other.

If we limit ourselves for a moment to one-particle path integrals, then a path integral is essentially a matrix element of the evolution operator (I might be skipping some nuaces here):
$$
G(x,t|x_0,t_0)=\langle x|U(t,t_0)|x_0\rangle=\langle x|e^{iH(t-t_0)}|x_0\rangle
$$
The matrix element of an operator is then
$$
\langle x|O(t)|x'\rangle = \langle x|U(t,t_0)^\dagger |O(t_0)|U((t,t_0)|x'\rangle
=\\
\int dx_0\int dx_0' 
\langle x|U(t,t_0)^\dagger|x_0\rangle
\langle x_0 |O(t_0)|x_0'\rangle
\langle x_0'|U((t,t_0)|x'\rangle
=\\
\int dx_0\int dx_0' 
G(x_0,t_0|x,t)
\langle x_0 |O(t_0)|x_0'\rangle
G(x_0',t|x',t_0\rangle
$$
(I suggest rechecking my calculations, since I might be somewhat sloppy here.)
The disappointment here is that Heisenberg and Schrödinger picture are equivalent, that is they do not change the matrix elements. Thus, the result is the same that we would obtain, if we assumed the Schrödinger picture with evolving wave function. Path integral formalism inherently focuses on calculating the matrix element, bypassing operator-wave function dichotomy, which is why the notion of 'operator time evolution' is not a very meaningful one here. I have even heard people speaking of distinguishing three representations: Schrödinger, Heisenberg and, the path integral one.
